# iOS: Model-Architecture in Apps

Tags: ios, xcode, model-view-controller, architecture

I did find some suggestions for this topic but still there are some things left open for me.

The question is about designing an app (from a development point of view) especially concerning models.

For example, I'm building an app with the Facebook SDK. I guess it would make sense to have a model class for the communication with the Facebook API. And i guess it would make sense to make this class a singleton (doesn't have to be).

But the Facebook SDK for iOS builds on delegates. So you send a request and the response returns in a delegate method in the model. That's okay, but I also would like to assign a delegate to the model so that the view controller is then called.

So, for example, a view controller uses the Facebook-singleton-model to make a request but wants to set itself as a delegate for this request, so that the model calls this delegate when the request is finished.
But this model is a singleton it only has one delegate (and i want it to keep it like this).
So do i overwrite the delegate pointer in the Facebook-singleton before each call? (No good, because another request might start in the meantime using the same singleton and the delegate would be overwritten again).

So what is a good architecture? What are best practices for reusing models across an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using singletons for my models which works really well with the following thread-safe code of getting a sharedInstance (the singleton)

```
+(QuizManager *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static QuizManager *shared = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[QuizManager alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
```

Working great is also the usage of **Key-Value-Observing (KVO)** in iOS. I can watch for changes on properties in the model and react in the view-controller. IMO this allows to create very clean and understandable code. (look it up and love it at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

On one point I'm also using a Model and set it up as a delegate and gave it a set of delegates which than broadcasts the delegation methods to all observers, which i find is also kind of nice.

Answer (score 2):

My advice here is to create your own delegate's protocol and register viewControllers as delegate of your singleton model. You're free to do that in many ways, you can have multiple delegates (by keeping delegates in array inside singleton).

Comment: My Facebook-model already has a custom protocol which is used by another model again. So actually it's going View Controller -> UserManagement Model -> Facebook Model.

This makes this whole delegate-work not easier..